# Ninject, using two way property injection to resolve cyclic dependency

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

Based on the answers in this question: [Cyclic dependency with ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511547/cyclic-dependency-with-ninject) and this questions: [Ninject: give the parent instance to a child being resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180280/ninject-give-the-parent-instance-to-a-child-being-resolved) both of these say you can use two way property injection to resolve cyclic dependencies as long as you change the scope to not be the default Transient Scope. So I tried doing that, I've got a `UserService` and a `GroupService` that require each other (and please don't say change the classes or use a third class, etc.!). I've got a generic `EntityServiceFactory` that uses ninject like so:

```
public static class EntityServiceFactory
{
    public static TServiceClass GetService<TServiceClass>()
        where TServiceClass : class
    {
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    return kernel.Get<TServiceClass>();
    }
}
```

And my services:

```
public class GroupService : EntityService<GroupRepository, Group, DbContext>
{
    public UserService _userService { private get; set; }


    public GroupService(GroupRepository repository, UserService userService) : base(repository)
    {
        userService._groupService = this;
    }

public class UserService : EntityService<UserRepository, User, DbContext>
{
    public GroupService _groupService { private get; set; }

    public UserService(UserRepository repository, GroupService groupService)
        : base(repository)
    {
        groupService._userService = this;
    }
```

Then as per the instructions in the answers to those questions add the following to my `EntityServiceFactory`:

```
kernel.Bind<GroupService>().ToSelf().InCallScope();
kernel.Bind<UserService>().ToSelf().InCallScope();
```

But I still get the Error:

> A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two
>   services.

Am I doing the two way property injection correctly? How do I resolve this?

Comment: I dont know the answer, but that is a well formed question. +1.

Comment: I know you insist in us not nagging about your design, but could you explain why those two services need to depend on each other?

Comment: btw. the usage of your `EntityServiceFactory` smells like the Service Locator anti-pattern. You might want to read [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) to verify if the use of this pattern could be problematic in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the article. The design can't change due to how our framework was built using auto-generated code. Also because of the inheritance chain of these classes and the use of generics, pulling out shared logic into a third class would not be possible without duplicating a ton of code that doesn't need to be duplicated. I came up with 3 solutions to this problem, this one being the easiest to implement while also breaking the least amount of "standards".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, turns out I didn't understand the answers in the questions I linked. I didn't do anything like property injection at all, what I ended up doing was this:

Anytime there was a cyclic dependency I would remove one of the cyclic-inducing services from the constructor and replace it with this:

```
    private UserService _userService;
    private UserService UserService
    {
        get { return _userService ?? (_userService = EntityServiceFactory.GetService<UserService>()); }
    }
```

This actually ended up being extremely close to what property injection is (http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Injection%20Patterns). It's not as optimal as constructor injection, but still isn't a bad solution. I also could have done this (actual property injection):

```
    private UserService _userService;
    [Inject]
    private UserService UserService
    {
        get { return _userService; }
        set { _userService = value; }
    }
```

I just chose my way since it doesn't require my services have ninject specific code in case I ever changed my usage of it, but called `EntityServiceFactory.GetService` is essentially doing the same thing as the `[Inject]` attribute.